# Spring JPA - how to allow duplicate entries for @Id

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am querying a view which joins three tables and returns the result like below:

```
select * from v_project_details

Project_ID  Repo_Name Branch_Name
100         Repo1      Branch1
100         Repo1      Branch2
101         Repo2      Branch2

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name='v_project_details')
public class ProjectDetails{

@Id
@Column(name="Project_Id")
private int ProjectId
}

@Column(name="Repo_Name")
private String RepoName
}

@Column(name="Branch_Name")
private String BranchName
}

@Query(select p from v_project_details p)
List<ProjectDetails> findAll();

Results:

Project_ID  Repo_Name Branch_Name
100         Repo1      Branch1
100         Repo1      Branch1 - I am expecting Branch2 here
101         Repo2      Branch2
```

when i query the table from spring jpa, i see three results but first row is repeated twice.

Looks like hibernate is not reinstantiating the object if @Id value is repeated more than once in the result set.

How do i force it to reinstantiate the object ? I do not have an unique identifier in the view as my view is joined from different tables.

Comment: Why is your `Project_ID` column not marked as `PRIMARY KEY` in your SQL table?

Comment: *how to allow duplicate entries for @Id* primary keys are supposed to be unique.

Comment: You can simply remove the `@Id` on your project_id field. Consider having a separate `@Id` annotated field called ProjectDetailsId. 

Looks like your projectId would be a foreign key reference to a project entity -- not the primary id of your project detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Id` is used by JPA to identify the primary key. In your case, `project_id` as your primary key, which JPA understands that both row1 and row2 as same records. If `project_id` is not your unique identifier for your records but instead a combination of multiple fields like (eg: combination of `project_id`, `repo_name` and `branch_name`), you need to define a composite primary key based on those 3 fields. refer to below post by baledung to know more on composite primary keys.

[Composite primary keys with JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys)

Answer (score 2):

JPA defines `@Id` as primary key field. Here is how w3scools defines primary key. Cite from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP

> The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a table.
>
> Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values, and cannot contain NULL values.
>
> A table can have only ONE primary key; and in the table, this primary key can consist of single or multiple columns (fields).

So, primary key is always unique and prohibits null values.

JPA implementations can make use of it and store items effectively with assumption that `@Id` is always unique.

Your `Project_ID` can't be `@Id` since it's not unique, so you should remove this annotation and everything should work as expected. JPA requires entity to have primary key, so you can define composite key or include row number in your view, so you can make row number primary key.

Comment: I get an error with out the @Id for entity : No Identifier specified for the entity.

Comment: @Srinivas, I've added a note regarding `@Id` annotation